# If $K(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ what is $n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, suppose Grothendieck group $K(X)$ is a free abelian group $K(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. Is it true that rank $n$ is the topological Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$ of $X$?

I saw this claim in a paper for two dimensional case $\dim X = 2$, but it was without proof.

Comment: I don't know much about algebraic varieties but in topology the Euler characteristic can be negative (e.g. [cubohemioctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubohemioctahedron) has the Euler characteristic $-2$). Is that impossible for algebraic varieties?

Comment: Condition that $K(X)$ is free abelian group of finite rank is very restrictive (e.g. if $X$ is a curve then $X\cong \mathbb{P}^1$), and my question implies that for such varieties Euler characteristic is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer.

Define an affine stratification of a variety $X$ as a decomposition of $X$ into a finite disjoint union of affine spaces $X_i=\Bbb A^{n_i}$ so that the closure of $X_i$ is again a disjoint union of $X_j$s. Then it is known result that any $X$ which admits an affine stratification has a free Grothendieck group, freely generated by the classes of $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{X_i}}$. (I'm pretty sure this argument is in Eisenbud & Harris' book on intersection theory, but my copy is packed away in a box right now and I can't get at it).

I don't know that this proposition is an equivalence (going backwards seems difficult, I would think), but in the case where your variety does in fact have an affine stratification, it provides exactly the result you're looking for. Calculate the topological Euler characteristic by treating each $\Bbb A^{n_i}$ as a cell homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{2n_i}$, then check that the free generating set is in bijective correspondence with the set of even-dimensional cells. Since there are no odd-dimensional cells, one sees that the Euler characteristic exactly matches the number of generators.

Comment: Thanks for this class of examples, but it would be very surprising for me if freeness of $K(X)$ is equivalent to existence of affine stratification.